# Which is better @Data of lombok or manual Getter and Setter in spring boot application in terms of performance?

Tags: java, spring-boot

In DTO class I need to add getter and setter and to do this we have 2 option either use Lombok api to add all getter setter automatically or manually add all required methods. So In terms of performance which one is preferred ?

Comment: Lombok analyzes the annotations and generates bytecode at compile time, so there's no performance difference at runtime, but it can affect the compilation time.

Comment: That is the same

Comment: AFAIK Lombok is an annotation processor, after compilation there is no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways performance is influenced by Lombok:

1. There is overhead when **building, releasing and deploying** your application because (1) there is an additional Lombok library involved. This would mean more data to transfer and (2) when compiling your code, the machine has more to compile.

What the exact overhead would be? The latest .jar is only 1,9mb! In regard of compiling, it depends on how many times you are requesting a Lombok annotation and how many DTO's you have. Modern machines and developed applications can handle Lombok without issues.

2. There is no overhead in **running your application** with Lombok because once the code is compiled, the exact principles stay the same for the code (constructors, getters/setters, etc.). There should only be performance issues when you have memory leaks in your code. There are several ways for analyzing memory leaks. However I don't see issues with memory leaks the way Lombok works.